# Vue Router Dynamic Route access to PARAMS

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I work with dynamic routes similar a this form:

**router.js**

```
...
{
 path: "/init/clients/moral-person/:company",
 name: "moralPerson",
 component: () => import('../MoralPerson.vue'),
 meta: {
   auth: true,
   breadcrumb: [
     { text: "Init", disabled: false, name: "init" },
     { text: "Clients", disabled: true, name: "" },
     { text: "Moral Person", disabled: false, name: "crudMoralPerson"},
     { text: "Company", disabled: true, name: "", icon: "fas fa-dollar-sign"},
   ]
 }
} 
...
```

NOTE: The part of breadcrumb is render for other component.

When I do router.push is this:

**Some File**

```
...

this.$router.push({
  name: "moralPerson",
  params: { company: this.nameCompany }
});
...
```

Finally looks similar this:

[image: Result]

I try to use the this.router.params, in this case **:company** and colocate in the part blue I mark or here:

**router.js**

```
...
     // in this line
     { text: :company, disabled: true, name: "", icon: "fas fa-dollar-sign"},
...
```

My question is, How access this param and colocate in this part I need?

**EDIT**

I try with:

```
...
{ text: this.$route.params.empresa, disabled: true, name: "", icon: "fas fa-dollar-sign"},
...
```

And always send me:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like  this:

```
  {
    path: '/init/clients/moral-person/:company'
    name: 'moralPerson',
    component: () => import('../MoralPerson.vue'),
    meta() {
      return {
        auth: true,
        breadcrumb: [
          { text: 'Init', disabled: false, name: 'init' },
          { text: 'Clients', disabled: true, name: '' },
          { text: 'Moral Person', disabled: false, name: 'crudMoralPerson' },
          { text: this.params.company, disabled: true, name: '', icon: 'fas fa-dollar-sign' },
        ],
      };
    },
  },
```

When you call the meta function, try this `this.$route.meta()`, because now the `meta` property is a function.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Let see, in your router configuration you are indicating that moralPerson component will receive a param called company, isn't it?

```js
this.$router.push({
  name: "moralPerson",
  params: { company: this.nameCompany }
});
```

The code above is correct, you must call your component using name if you want to pass some params.
To access this param you must do the following, mainly inside **created** lifecycle function:

```js
this.$route.params.company
```

I hope this could help you